# How to make a silence?

Tags: audio

I am trying to make a method in my simple application which is like `SetSilence();` Now If I have audio (mono) PCM 16 bit Signed - should I fill all data with 0 values? And for PCM 16 Unsigned with 32768 values?

Comment: Aren't there libraries that do this sort of thing for you?

Comment: If I can do something at my own, I'm doing it. I like to know what is inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Other values would cause a DC offset.